# Oracle database (online) replication

Tags: java, database, oracle, oracle11g

I am a Java guy, I can work with Oracle Database, I know PLSQL, SQL. But I am not good at managing database servers. I think it is a completely different area.

My question is related to database replication. I googled it, found millions of answers but I am still confused.

I could see many times in my professional carrier that developers create complete (complicated) applications to keep sync the source database schema to a target one. It takes time to develop sync apps and very hard to maintain them, especially in case of any data structure modification for example in tables.

I could see that apps built with JPA, JDBC, Spring, myBatis, and PLSQL as well. Usually, they sync DBs during the night, scheduled by Cron, Quartz, Spring, etc. During the sync process usually, the source DB is only available for querying data, not for inserting and DB constraints and triggers are disabled.

These kinds of custom applications always scare me. I do not believe that there is no general, easy, and official way to keep sync two databases without developing a new application.

Now, I got a similar task and honestly, I would like to write zero lines of code related to this task. I believe that there are recommended and existing solutions, cover this topic offered by the database vendors.

That would be great if you can push me in the right direction. I feel that writing another new DB sync application is not the right way.

I need to focus on Oracle Database sync, but I would be happy to know a general,  database vendor-independent way.

Comment: Is this a production database? In other words, what does `SELECT log_mode FROM v$database` say?

Comment: what is the use of the replicated database, how will you use it? that makes a huge difference on the solution chosen to replicate the data.

Comment: @wolφi: Error: ORA-00904: "LOG_MODE": invalid identifier

Comment: @CyrilleMODIANO It will be used for a WEB UI, mainly query the data.

Comment: @wolφi - log_mode doesn't prove or disprove that the database is 'production'. Many people run test databases in archivelog mode. And unfortunately, some people run production in NOarchivelog.  And what does it being production, or not, have to do with answering the OP's questions?

Comment: @zappee if you don't plan on doing modification to the replicated database you should go with active dataguard. Real Time replicated database open in read only for queries.

Comment: @EdStevens If the database is in archivelog mode, then we can suggest zappee to use one of the redo log-copying tools. If it's a production system, then this is hopefully true.

Comment: @wolφi - I agreed that production systems _should_ be in archivelog mode, but there is no guarantee of such. And being production or test has nothing to do with the technical solution. Yet your leading question was "is it production?" The real question is not prod vs test, but archivelog vs. NOarchivelog. And while I am not familiar with products like Golden Gate, it seems reasonable that they might work with the online redo and not the archivelogs.

Comment: @EdStevens This is not about guarantees, but about communication with people asking questions! And no, Golden Gate et al. do need the archivelogs, they even block the deletion until they are applied to the target database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to perform replication in a Oracle Database.  Oracle has two replication techniques in the database "Advanced Replication" and "GoldenGate".   GoldenGate us the new perferred method of replication which uses the redo logs files from the database.  Both methods are geared for a Oracle DBA.

Often application developers will create a "interface" that will move data from one database to other.   A interface is a program ( pl/sql, bash, c, etc ) that runs on a cron (database or system) that wakes on a event to move data.  Interfaces are useful when data is needed to be process during replication.

Comment: Yes, we use GoldenGate at work. It started out as a vendor independent tool, which was bought by Oracle. Before that, we used Quest Shareplex, also vendor independent. Both cost a lot of money and need some skills to run and to maintain.

Comment: I know "interfaces" very well. Specially interfaces, written in Java, executed in application servers. But I would like to avoid to make any interface. We do not want to transform or process data, just replicate them. I will ask the DB team about the licences we have.

Comment: They will know about ARCHIVELOG as well (which is needed for the replication of the redo log files @Golden has mentioned).  I've heard the names Data Guard and Standby Database, as well.